# How to redirect to a specific screen after main.dart upon reopening app from foreground?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I have a Flutter application with push notifications through flutter_local_notifications. When the app is open, I press the "Home" button on the iPhone 12 emulator. Then, when a push notification is pressed, I can see what the payload of said notification is in main.dart with a listener:

```
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
      onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {

        if (payload != null) {
          debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');

        }

  });
```

What I'm trying to do is redirect to a specific screen if the payload (String) is equal to a specific value like so:

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
          onSelectNotification: (String? payload) async {
    
            if (payload != null) {
              debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    
            }

            if (payload == "test") {
               // navigate to test screen instead of home screen
            }
    
      });
```

One of the issues I'm seeing is that "context" is unavailable, even after importing dependency. Is this functionality possible?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a flutter [dynamic links](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_dynamic_links)